# Как вставить файл из папки в postgresql?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Как из папки на компьютере ( не из корневой папки бд ) вставить файл в одно из полей таблицы.
Нужно что-то типа

```
insert into test(idserial, contenttext)
values (4, нужнаяфункция('D:\html\ex02.xml'));
```

Знаю, что можно использовать copy, pg_read_file, но не понимаю как.
P.S. Просто вставить текст из файла xml я могу, нужно именно вставлять файл из папки.

Comment: Можно вместо файла вставить полный путь к нему, например.

Comment: @m9_psy Нужно чтобы каким-то образом текст попадал в поле таблицы, так у меня почему-то не получается, а про полный путь не понял - как его указать, чтобы его принял values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insert into test(idserial, contenttext)
values (4, pg_read_file('ex02.xml'));
```

Два момента: `pg_read_file` разрешено использовать только суперпользователю по соображениям безопасности. Если вы понимаете, что делаете, то обойти это ограничение возможно, например, созданием новой функции от имени суперпользователи и помеченной как security definer. От суперпользователя объявление функции:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_text_document(p_filename CHARACTER VARYING)
  RETURNS TEXT AS $$
  SELECT pg_read_file($1);
$$ LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Затем можно её использовать от обычного пользователя

```
insert into test(idserial, contenttext)
values (4, get_text_document('ex02.xml'));
```

Второй момент более проблемный: читать так можно только из директории, где лежит сама база или логи. Относительный путь выше по иерархии так же запрещён. Поэтому необходимо либо файл перебросить в нужное место, либо использовать симлинк на директорию (хотя надо бы проверить, вдруг и по симлинку ходить откажется) либо использовать другой способ.

Есть [вариант через `large object`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2962), опять же хранимка от суперпользователя:

```
create or replace function bytea_import(p_path text, p_result out bytea) 
                   language plpgsql as $$
declare
  l_oid oid;
  r record;
begin
  p_result := '';
  select lo_import(p_path) into l_oid;
  for r in ( select data 
             from pg_largeobject 
             where loid = l_oid 
             order by pageno ) loop
    p_result = p_result || r.data;
  end loop;
  perform lo_unlink(l_oid);
end;$$;
```

Оригинальная функция возвращает bytea, не стал это изменять в самой функции. Перекодировать можно вот так:

```
insert into test(idserial, contenttext)
values (4, convert_from(bytea_import('/etc/fstab'), 'utf8'));
```

Можно использовать [отдельное расширение](https://github.com/csimsek/pgsql-fio/) с базовыми функциями ввода-вывода.

Или можно обратиться опять же к хранимым языкам, но помеченным как небезопасные: `pl/perlu` или `pl/pythonu`. Небезопасные они как раз потому, что могут обращаться в том числе к файловой системе беспрепятственно от имени пользователя базы данных. [Например](https://stackoverflow.com/a/880642):

```
CREATE FUNCTION gettext(url TEXT) RETURNS TEXT
AS $$
import urllib2
try:
  f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  return ''.join(f.readlines())
except Exception:
  return ""
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;

insert into test(idserial, contenttext)
values (4, gettext('file://D:\html\ex02.xml'));
```

Comment: Написал 
`ALTER USER postgres WITH SUPERUSER;`

но `insert into test(idserial, contenttext)
values (4, get_text_document('ex02.xml'));`

всё равно выдаёт "абсолютный путь недопустим"

Comment: О, да, пропустил момент `Only files within the database cluster directory and the log_directory can be accessed.`. Читать можно только из директории самой базы. Буду дописывать ответ

Comment: Большущее спасибо, весьма благодарен.